# Powder Physics Games

Tags: physics, microsoft-dynamics, fluid

Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing?

I'm talking about applets like this http://dan-ball.jp/en/javagame/dust/

I'm really interested in how they work, it seems more like fluid-dynamics than regular game physics. Does anyone know any open source variations, or any hints on how they might work? I think it would be really fun and challenging to work on something like this, but I'm not sure where to start researching...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place you can look is at [Processing.org](http://processing.org).  There you can find some examples of those types of programs, including the source and some decent explanations.  It is java-like, but not entirely java.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with both [phys2d](http://www.cokeandcode.com/phys2d/) and [jbox2d](http://www.jbox2d.org/). I find Phys2d is easier to use.

Comment: I've used them both too, but it really isn't the right sort of thing for applying to this